# Minify HTML for use in JavaScript using Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails project where I'm going to take the HTML output from a controller and use it inside a bit of JavaScript that I'm creating. I need to minify the HTML output from the controller, but being that I'm going to be using the output in some generated JavaScript I really want to be absolutely sure it always crams down to a single line.

For the context of the question, I'd really like advice only on the part about how I can use Ruby to minify the HTML as described.

This is just pseudo-code, but it attempts to explain the process I'm going through.

```
# ruby
@html = output_from_controller
@html = minify_html(@html)

# erb generating javascript
var html = "<%== @html %>";
```

Comment: `escape_javascript()` will apply escaping to ensure the html wont break a js string

Comment: I can't believe how many useful tools Rails has it! Wow that looks like exactly what I need. [escape_javascript()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript)